# Charges for "traffic" in EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Is there any changes for "traffic" when using basic version of EC2 instance, by basic I mean:

750 hours per month of Linux, RHEL, or SLES t2.micro instance usage

Traffic: If we setup a server and there are some hits on my server then is there any charge for this setup. I am not using ELB, just EC2 instance with a server on it.

Comment: it means simply you get 750 hours of compute time on ec2 server. even if it sitting completely idle or all the time busy serving the traffic, it will be calculated as 750 hours, unless you stop/terminate the instance.

Comment: @AmitK yeah, even though we have 750 hrs there are charges for traffic we get in the EC2 server. Please check the answer section.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The full pricing for On-Demand Amazon EC2 instances can be found at: https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/on-demand/

The [AWS Free Usage Tier](https://aws.amazon.com/free/) gives 750 hours per month of a `t2.micro` instance. This means you could run one instance for a full month, or two instances for half a month. Simply stop the instance(s) to stop the charges.

You can have this free usage tier for a Linux *AND* a Windows instance.

However, please note that there are additional charges that also apply:

- **Data Transfer:** This is charged for data leaving the AWS Region going to the Internet. The free usage tier includes "15 GB of bandwidth out aggregated across all AWS services" in the first 12 months. The EC2 pricing page also says that the first 1 GB/month is free, but I'm not sure if they overlap.
- **EBS Volume storage:** Elastic Block Store (EBS) runs the disks attached to your instance. The free usage tier includes "30 GB of Amazon Elastic Block Storage in any combination of General Purpose (SSD) or Magnetic, plus 2 million I/Os (with EBS Magnetic) and 1 GB of snapshot storage", so you will be charged if your disk storage exceeds this (which is likely if you run both a Windows and a Linux instance). This storage charge continues to apply when an instance is Stopped, but not when an instance is Terminated.

**Bottom line:** Stop or turn off things when you don't need them. You can also activate a [billing alert](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/free-tier-alarms.html) to warn you when you have been charged some actual money.

Comment: For reference, data transfer section: https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/on-demand/#Data_Transfer

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there are varying charges for traffic into and out of your EC2 instance.

in very rough numbers, if you budgeted $0.01 per GB of traffic, you would come in under that, but the complete breakdown is here:

https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/on-demand/